# update Kivy progressbar by gpio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am having troubles getting my code to work. The progressbar should move on when a button is pressed and jump to 0 when it is released. With the kivy built in functions on_touch_down and on_touch_up it works but with my own check input funtion some arguments are missing. How do I pass them in correctly?

Thanks in advance!

```
import kivy

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.clock import Clock

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

buttonPin1 = 14
pbVal = 0

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

Builder.load_string('''
<MainGrid>

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Label:
                text: "Tipp"

            Label:
                text: "Vid"

        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            ProgressBar:
                id: pb
                min: 0
                max: 100
''')


class MainGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def update_bar(self,*args):
        global pbVal
        pbVal = pbVal+1
        self.ids.pb.value=pbVal

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print('ButtonPressed')
        self.event=Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_bar, 1.0/10.0)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        global pbVal
        print('ButtonReleased')
        self.event.cancel()
        pbVal = 0
        self.ids.pb.value=pbVal

    def checkInput(self,*args):
        global pbVal
        if GPIO.input(buttonPin1) == True:
            print("not pressed")
            self.event.cancel()
            pbVal = 0
            self.ids.pb.value=pbVal
        else:
            print("pressed")
            self.event=Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_bar, 1.0/10.0)

    Clock.schedule_interval(checkInput, 1.0/10.0)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainGrid()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Btw, I know that the input funtion will not properly work such as the on_touch_down/up funtion as i will jump in continuously. I just copy pasted the code from the touch_down and up functions

Answer (score 0):

Someone found out the solution for my problem in the kivy forum already!

The clock command must be called from within the init section, the the checkInputs functions receives all the necessary attributes:

```
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(checkInput, 1.0/10.0)
```